# Is there a solution to this freecell game?

Tags: free-cell

Does a solution exist, see attached image?

[image: Freecell Game]

Answer (score 8):

**Yes.**

Put the puzzle into [this solver](http://fc-solve.shlomifish.org/js-fc-solve/text/) and it gives a solution.

The encoding of the puzzle is:

```
9S AD 8H 2S 4C 10S QS
6D AC 9D 10C 4H 4S 9H
9C 8S JD 7D 3S JS QC
5S KS 8C 3H 5C 5D 2H
QH JH 4D QD 2C 7S
7H JC 8D 10H 10D KC
2D AH KD 5H 7C 3C
6H AS KH 6S 6C 3D
```